# Service stop working when turn on /of wifi many time

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

Service stop working when turn on /of Wi-Fi many time, when I start service do counter 1,2,3 etc or any thing then turn on /of Wi-Fi many time the service stops working ,I have BroadcastReceiver class doing start service, no exceptions , error appear , only I sent one message to phone to start service..

This is the code inside BroadcastReceiver:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))    {
Intent recorderIntent = new Intent(context, Start2.class);
context.startService(recorderIntent);
}
```

This My Start2 Service:

```
public class Start2 extends Service {

private static final String TAG = Start2.class.getSimpleName();
int mStartMode;


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   Log.d(TAG, "Stop Service onDestroy");
}

 @Nullable
 @Override
 public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {


return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            int i = 0 ;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    //do your code here
                    Log.d(TAG, "Start Service Repeat Time.. " + i);
                    i++;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                finally{
                    //also call the same runnable to call it at regular interval
                    handler.postDelayed( this, 5000 );
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000 );

        return null;
    }
};
task.execute();


return mStartMode;
}
}
```

Comment: did you register receiver, service and get permission in Manifest?

Comment: Are you expecting it to run forever or something?  It won't.  Android will stop your service, when it decides to do so, for any of a number of reasons...